# Change table row styleclass under certain mysql conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table created with a foreach loop.

```
  **foreach($data2['wow_accounts']['0']['characters'] as $key => $item) {

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo  $item['name'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo  $item['realm']['name'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo  '<button class="btnSelect">Select</button>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';**
```

I want that the script checks inside of the table "y4qt2_jsn_users" of the mysql database **and under a certain id number**, if the "params" entry is "ja". If this is true then this certain table row should get another tr class.

My idea is something like that, but how can i combine this with my foreach table loop?

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT params FROM xxx_users WHERE params = 'ja' AND id= '$id'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
     // row not found, just loop without a certain <tr class=""
} else {
    // row found, give this row a <tr class=""
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I want. If the mysql condition "params=ja" is true the whole row should get a new tr styleclass, not just a cell.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L53Sr.png)

[Screenshot-Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aBo6.png)

Comment: You say table row gets a class but your comments use a table cell. You also don't describe where $id comes from and in general this is hard to follow. I'm going to take a stab at it, but if you can clarify some, it will help you get a suitable answer.

Comment: Thanks for help. You´re right. I mean a tr class. I´ve added a screenshot to my thread and made it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly, this should work. Please sanitize database queries (especially if there is user input at any point). But as mentioned in the comments, I don't know where `$id` is set, and actually presume it's a value in the `$item` array, so maybe replaced with `$item['Id']`

```
foreach($data2['wow_accounts']['0']['characters'] as $key => $item) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT params FROM y4qt2_jsn_users WHERE params = 'ja' AND 
    id= '$id'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
         $class_string = '';
    } else {
        $class_string = ' class="my-additional-class"';
    }

    echo '<tr'.$class_string.'>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo  $item['name'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo  $item['realm']['name'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo  '<button class="btnSelect">Select</button>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

There are a lot of ways to clean this up, and if you wanted fewer lines of code you can replace the entire if else block and the `$class_string` variable by using [ternary operators](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) inline. The goal was to make it easy for you to read and simple to understand. (I also prefer very verbose code myself)

Comment: Thankyou. The row isn´t changing the class/ color for some reason. In the html output it´s still <tr> on the row which fulfilled the criteria. I´ve changed to mysqli, but no changes. I´ll put a screenshot of the databse in my starting thread. The $id is set out of an array before and it gives the right output (294).